# PropertyPermission access denied in JWS launch

Tags: java, jar, jnlp, executable-jar, java-web-start

I new to web-start and We are using exe4j to create executable from One-jar. In-order to make a "web start version" of our application I am trying to lunch One-JAR using web start with the specified Main-Class but I am getting the following error -

```
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission one-jar.main-class read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:186)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

JNLP contains --

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Applet Takes Params</title>
        <vendor>Protype example</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.5+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="Application.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot">
  </application-desc>
   <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I am trying to launch a **Application.jar** directly and **com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot** is the main class specify for JAR. I am also found this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/one-jar/forums/forum/380843/topic/1788843) that says we can not launch One-Jar with web-start. please help.

Comment: BTW - it would be a good idea to validate the JNLP(s) using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: BTW - I just looked into [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) more closely. *"One-JAR provides custom classloader that knows how to load classes and resources from a jars inside an archive"*  JWS Clients do not.  They use a standard class-loader.  The best way to deploy the Jars using JWS is by adding a reference to each jar in the `resources` element.  Take advantage of efficient updates by specifying some as `lazy` download.

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you if it work.

Comment: Should I try to launch One-Jar with JWS or should try to launch original source code jar by specifying reference of each JAR in resources?

Comment: Use the 2nd suggestion *"specifying reference of each JAR in resources"* (of JNLP).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292837/does-jws-support-to-launch-one-jar

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will definitely go for 2nd option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission one-jar.main-class read)
```

A web start app. can access any property if it declares `all-permissions`.  If it is sand-boxed, it can only access properties prefixed with `jnlp` & some other JRE properties that are considered 'safe'.

Comment: Thanks but I am new to web start. can you please elaborate that you are suggesting?

Comment: I have edited my original post too. Added Image from which I am taking reference to specify main class.

Comment: The screen-shot does not help me to help you in any way.  Mostly because I do not provide support for IDEs.