# does JWS support to launch One-Jar

Tags: resources, classpath, jnlp, executable-jar, java-web-start

Can I supposed to launch [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) using JWS? One-JAR provides custom classloader that knows how to load classes and resources from a jars inside an archive whereas in JWS we need to specify each JAR that is being used in resources.

What I supposed to specify in JNLP if I am trying to launch [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Application</title>
        <vendor>ABC</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.5+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="Application.jar" main="true" download="eager" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot">
  </application-desc>
   <update check="background"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
</jnlp>
```

My Application JAR that is One-JAR contains -

```
com\simontuffs\onejar\<contains complied classes> like JarClassLoader$1.class etc
lib/<contains all jar>
OneJar.class
main/<my application's jar>
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF\ <contains >

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: One-Jar 0.96 Ant taskdef
Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot
One-Jar-Main-Class: com.application.main.Entry

Name: com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot$3.class
SHA1-Digest: +LPrezs+UEFcE3J7QvumcAEO8Z0=

Name: OneJar.class
SHA1-Digest: 28pzzJWqEpLk1xFwJ/jsAav8LyI=

Name: lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
SHA1-Digest: qHYtB+ds/eI5Ulel2ke6fB29Pc4=
```

etc..etc..

How to specify these **com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot$3.class** paths in resource ?

Comment: I don't know why you are [persisting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269698/propertypermission-access-denied-in-jws-launch) with One-Jar for this JWS based deployment.  Not only will it not work, but it loses many of the advantages that JWS offers by keeping Jars separate!  Either way, I am unable to assist further with the JWS/One-Jar conundrum.  Sorry..

Comment: I am sorry Andrew but I am not sticking with One-Jar. I am looking a strong reason to avoid One-JAR because 1. We always need to keep updating JNLP if any JAR version updated or if we added a new JAR in our application. 2. We are already using One-Jar for our java-desktop version. so this same jar would be use for desktop as well as for web version. I hope you will guide me in my these two assumptions. Thanks

Comment: @ "loses many of the advantages that JWS offers by keeping Jars separate!" - Andrew. Can you please let me know what are the advantages ? All Jars must be sign and they all will download separately.

Comment: :) okay. "what are the advantages that JWS offers by keeping Jars separate vs One-JAR? I need a detail description and a strong reason for -- why not to use One-Jar with JWS ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293899/what-are-the-advantages-that-jws-offers-by-keeping-jars-separate-vs-one-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem of supporting tools like One-Jar is that loading Jars within Jars requires a custom class-loader.  By default JWS will use the usual JRE class-loaders - which do not support it.

There are two possible ways that you might get around that (that I know of).

### 1. Get access to the custom class-loader.

Get an instance of the custom loader used by One-Jar and set it as the context class-loader.  This would require a trusted app., but I get the impression that your app. is trusted.

I have no idea if the One-Jar API provides this loader for your own app.'s use.

### 2. Use some options when building.

From [Options and VM Properties](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=details&file=options)..

**`one-jar.jar.names`**

- `true`:  Recorded classes are kept in directories corresponding to their jar names.
- `false`: Recorded classes are flattened into a single directory.
                          Duplicates are ignored (first wins)

The 2<sup>nd</sup> option sounds like a standard 'fat jar'.  That should work with the conventional (default) class-loader used by JWS.

Comment: Where should I write code to access the costume class loader ? I am trying to launch application using JNLP and program control is not reaching up-to main method of the main class.

Comment: That is option 1. and if it is not reaching main, it seems that is not a **viable** option (not something that will solve the problem).  Try option 2.  BTW - 'custom' & 'costume' are very different words. ;)

Comment: Yes.. :-) on the different note - sorry for all that happened. Please let me know the advantages offered by JWS if I specify each JAR in JNLP?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. now we are trying to launch simple jar NOT One-JAR.

Comment: Can you help me in another issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352840/how-net-mvc-application-can-communicate-with-core-java-desktop-application-usin

Comment: It seems that question has already been answered by Raghuram.