# what are the advantages that JWS offers by keeping Jars separate vs One-Jar?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am trying to launch One-Jar using JWS but it could not make it launch. Can anybody suggest me a good approach to make web start version of application from my two options --

## 1. Launch [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) using JWS

Have anyone tried this earlier? I am not getting success in this. Related [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292837/does-jws-support-to-launch-one-jar).

## 2. Launch simple application JAR by specifying each jar in property that are being used in application.

I am looking a strong reason to avoid One-JAR because

1. We always need to keep updating JNLP if any JAR version updated or if we added a new JAR in our application.
2. We are already using One-Jar for our java-desktop version. so this same jar would be use for desktop as well as for web version.
3. what are the advantages that JWS offers by keeping Jars separate?

Comment: Point 3 of 2, the question I suggested you ask, is something on which I could write a treatise.  Expect that in the next 24-48 hours.  I (again) suggest you limit it to one question per ..question and if other qns. are of that great interest to you, ask *them* on a separate thread!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294219/what-are-the-advantages-that-jws-offers-by-keeping-jars-separate

Comment: Given you've moved part of this question to a new question, it should be edited out, and the title changed.  Perhaps refocus it on 'can JWS/One-Jar co-exist?'..

Comment: JWS oses a custom classloader that might conflict with the one created by OneJar.