# how .net MVC application can communicate with Core java desktop application using JWS?

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, jnlp, java-web-start

We have a java desktop application and we are planning to launch that java desktop application using JWS and that is working absolutely fine.

The issue is -- we ask some user related information from user on web page and launch java desktop application using JWS. Now we would like to have that information provided by user on web page in our java application. Please suggest how we can access those information in java code ? We have find two approaches --

1. Can java code read that information from cookies ? I have not find any help how to read cookies using core java code ? again what if cookies are not enable on user's desktop ?
2. Can we pass information using JNLP file ? Can we write all information in JNLP file ? can pass as an argument to the java code ? does the length of the argument matter here ? can we get information from JNLP by some other way ?

Please suggest if you know another approach better then these above two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rule out approach 1.

Approach 2 is fine if the information is minimal.  In one of our projects, we dynamically generated the jnlp file, based on information received from the web interface, which resulted in the java application being customized for the user.

You could also have the application communicate with the backend (say over http) and pull more information as required.

Comment: Thanks Raghu. What will be the limit of information? Are you passing that information as an argument to the java code in main class or reading information by properties ?

Comment: @AshishPancholi.  The limit is determined by how clean and maintainable you want your app to be.  If I recall right, we passed an argument or two.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked you can pass number of arguments and I think there may be no limit.

Comment: One more help -- you said "You could also have the application communicate with the backend (say over http) and pull more information as required." can you suggest what type of application it could be ?

Comment: What I meant was, a desktop app can also communicate with a server over internet using http and alter its behavior or display data based on the information obtained.

Comment: why approach #1 is not feasible ?